# A ticker bar in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, ticker

I am thinking of ways to display data and what I had in mind was a sort of ticker, that users can switch between items on.

ie.

< Some text here... >

Where if the user clicks the left button, an animation causes the text to slide left and some new text to appear from the right. Likewise for clicking the right button.

Are there any existing WPF controls that would do this (I am quite new to WPF)? If not, how difficult would it be to make manually? I imagine I would need to use a storyboard to make the animation?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like You are talking about a Carousel control. It's not hard to make your own with a use of a ItemsControl, or ListBox where you slide the selected items into the view. There are some controls out there including one made by Telerik. Here're a couple of links to get you started, but just google "WPF Carousel"

http://wpfcarousel.codeplex.com/

http://www.telerik.com/products/wpf/carousel.aspx